# Google Analytics trackEvents in SQL Query Syntax Error

Tags: sql, character-encoding, special-characters, urlencode, varchar

Using an SQL Query I'm trying to compose a trackEvents onclick function but it comes out all wrong and I don't know how to escape the special characters in the query.

This is what I'm trying to get:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/download.pdf" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Download', 'PDF', 'Test Tracking']);">Test tracking</a>
```

Using this query:

```
SELECT
'<a href="' + downloadurl + '" class="pdf" onclick="_gaq.push(["_trackEvent",
"Download", "PDF", "' + prd.title + '"]);">Download</a>' as targetWebsite

FROM product prd

WHERE
id = @dbid@
and downloadurl <> ''
```

Current output:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/download.pdf" class="pdf" onclick="_gaq.push([" _trackevent",="" "download",="" "pdf",="" "title"]);"="">Download</a>
```

I would like to know how to escape the single quotes and perhaps find out why there are '=' chars and extra quotations in there. I've tried various things including a javascript function to make the sql string less complicated, it didn't work though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=escape+single+quote

Answer (score 0):

double the single quotes if you want to appear single quotes instead of double quotes, eg

```
DECLARE @downloadurl VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @title VARCHAR(50)
SET @downloadurl = 'http://domain.com/download.pdf'
SET @title = 'Test Tracking'


SELECT
'<a href="' + @downloadurl + '" class="pdf" onclick="_gaq.push([''_trackEvent'',
''Download'', ''PDF'', ''' + @title+ ''']);">Download</a>' as targetWebsite
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7570)